# How can I parse html page on web [from local]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a personal home-page.html, so it resides on my computer and it is accesible only from my browser. Now for example I want get all element `<a>` from an external page and put them into a `<div>` when I click a button. Is it possible using a javascript funtion or jquery ? 
I have found answers about different domains, but it is not my case. I want to make something like this:
https://jsoup.org/

and 
https://try.jsoup.org/~LGB7rk_atM2roavV0d-czMt3J_g 
.
I tried with `<frame>` or `load()`but with bad results...

I'm trying this:

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="txt"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://cnt.rm.ingv.it",
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                $('#txt').html($(data).find('a').html());
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #txt{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    #button{}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the requirement is possible.

Comment: can you accompany me near the answer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: thanks. it was useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ajax call for getting data and then get all  tag.
like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
           $('div').html($(data).find('a').html());
        }
});
```

here url is url of page from where you want data

I have try your code and it is working for me
I get out put like this

INGVL'IstitutoAmbienteVulcaniTerremotiComunicazioneStampa
Lista TerremotiStrumenti Prodotti Scientifici ISIDeBollettino

To get all 'a' tag please try below code

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://cnt.rm.ingv.it",
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                $(data).find('a').map(function(){
                    $('#txt').append($(this).html());
                });        
            }
        });
    });
```

let me know if not working

thanks

Comment: it's work. But why it return only one element ? and why I have in console many Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  ? the error refers to jpg file... but I'm searching < a >  or < table >